# Terraform: why does aws_security_group try to recreate this group despite the group being in tfstate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform always tries to create the `aws_security_group` resource below, despite containing the resource in in `.tfstate`.

I didn't think this was the behavior of this resource, as I had been able to use it before without any issues. However, after deleting some old security groups and creating a new vpc in the AWS console, `terraform apply` now yields: `400: The security group 'web-traffic' already exists for VPC`.

I am using this resource across a couple modules. But, I assume if the resource creation respects `.tfstate` this would only cause issues with parallelization before the resource exists in `.tfstate`. That is the not the scenario I am currently encountering; the resource already exists in `.tfstate`.

I've redacted the information below, but the `vpc_id` in `.tfstate` and the one used by the resource *do* match. The state isn't still pointing to a security group on the old vpc.

**Resource declaration:**

```hcl
# web_traffic.tf
module "vpc" {
  source = "../vpc"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "web_traffic" {
  name        = "web-traffic"
  description = "Allows web traffic on ports 443 and 8080"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.aws_vpc.id

  ingress {
    description      = "https"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description      = "http"
    from_port        = 8080
    to_port          = 8080
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "web-traffic"
  }
}

output "web_traffic" {
  value = aws_security_group.web_traffic
}
```

**.tfstate:**

```hcl
{
      "module": "module.deploy.module.security",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "aws_security_group",
      "name": "web_traffic",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 1,
          "attributes": {
            "arn": "<redacted>",
            "description": "Allows web traffic on ports 443 and 8080",
            "egress": [
              {
                "cidr_blocks": [
                  "0.0.0.0/0"
                ],
                "description": "",
                "from_port": 0,
                "ipv6_cidr_blocks": [
                  "::/0"
                ],
                "prefix_list_ids": [],
                "protocol": "-1",
                "security_groups": [],
                "self": false,
                "to_port": 0
              }
            ],
            "id": "<redacted>",
            "ingress": [
              {
                "cidr_blocks": [
                  "0.0.0.0/0"
                ],
                "description": "https",
                "from_port": 443,
                "ipv6_cidr_blocks": [
                  "::/0"
                ],
                "prefix_list_ids": [],
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "security_groups": [],
                "self": false,
                "to_port": 443
              },
              {
                "cidr_blocks": [
                  "0.0.0.0/0"
                ],
                "description": "http",
                "from_port": 8080,
                "ipv6_cidr_blocks": [
                  "::/0"
                ],
                "prefix_list_ids": [],
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "security_groups": [],
                "self": false,
                "to_port": 8080
              }
            ],
            "name": "web-traffic",
            "name_prefix": "",
            "owner_id": "<redacted>",
            "revoke_rules_on_delete": false,
            "tags": {
              "Name": "web-traffic"
            },
            "tags_all": {
              "Name": "web-traffic"
            },
            "timeouts": null,
            "vpc_id": "<redacted>"
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "<redacted>",
          "dependencies": [
            "module.deploy.module.security.module.vpc.data.aws_vpc.main"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: So the module you creates is unaware of the VPC you created manually?

Comment: No, the `aws_vpc` member of the `module "vpc"` refers to a `data "aws_vpc"` with the id of the vpc I want to use (the one I created manually).

Comment: Looks like this might solve my problem: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3341#issuecomment-157489417 Probably just need to remove the existing ec2 instances.

Comment: It would really help in answering your question if you would include the relevant `terraform plan` output. There are symbols in that output that generally indicate exactly why Terraform thinks it needs to recreate a resource.